# React + SSR + webpack + node, unexpected token �PNG

Tags: reactjs, webpack, urlloader, webpack-file-loader, server-side-rendering

I'm having webapp in react with server side rendering feature running on node server. I'm using local images from assets directory (as shown below:

```
<img src={require('../../../assets/img/image.png')} width="400" />
```

which is running fine on the client side, but on the server side, node tries to read the content of the image file and throw below mentioned error.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �PNG
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:605:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I've tried using file-loader, url-loader but nothing working.
webpack configuration for file-loader:

```
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
},
```

Can anyone please let me know what the issue here. Or is there any other way possible to use a local image other than `require()`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
~Satish

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Same for me, any solution? I set `emitFile` to false but still doesn't help...